# Logging errors in SCSF

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2005, scsf

I'm quite new to SCSF.
So, I'm developping a SCSF Winforms in C# (using May 2007 version in VSNet 2005 Fwk2.0, I can't use new version). I've implemented a Business module. What is the best practise to log errors? I've configured the Logging Application Block. But how to use that ?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

```
//Here is how I declare a "Type" logger
public static Log logger = Log.CreateForType(typeof(Entry));

//Then, when you wants to log something
logger.Verbose("This is an example");
```